# Not sure how to code current element to be false

Tags: ruby, mapreduce, maps, reduce

Working on the 4th line... trying to return false if current element is false. I know i need to add the boolean false.

```
def reduce_to_all_true(array)
  counter = 0 
  while counter < array.size do
    return false if (CONDITION)
    counter += 1
  end
  return true 
end
```

1) My own reduce-like methods reduce_to_all_true returns false when any value is false reduces correctly.

I keep getting a true value.

Comment: Suppose `condition` is a method that takes the argument `counter` and returns `true` if the condition is met and `false` otherwise. You could write `return false if !condition(counter)` or (better, imo) `return false unless condition(counter)`. By the way I doubt very much if any readers will be filtering on your tag `mapreduce`.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `false` is to be returned if an element of the array equals `7`; else `true` is to be returned.

```
def reduce_to_all_true(array)
  array.all? { |e| condition_met(e) } 
end

def condition_met(e)
  e != 7
end
```

Other conditions can be handled in the same way, using [Enumerable#all?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F). Note that Ruby terminates the enumeration of the array if and when it finds an element that does not meet the condition.